# Attaching class styles to links in mermaid

Tags: markdown, mermaid

I'm making a neural network diagram with mermaid and it would be very convenient if styling the links could be attached to the class of the attached elements. It doesn't seem possible but I wanted to ask before switching to another tool. (I'm just not counting dozens of links for styling)

If the activ class could also make the link yellow somehow that would be perfect.

Here's the MD

```
graph LR;
    classDef activ stroke:#F6BE00, stroke-width: 2px;

    a1((a1)):::activ-->b1((b1));
    a2((a2))-->b1;
    a3((a3))-->b1;
    a1-->b2((b2));
    a2-->b2;
    a3-->b2;
    a1-->b3((b3));
    a2-->b3;
    a3-->b3;
    a1-->b4((b4));
    a2-->b4;
    a3-->b4;
    b1-->c1((c1));
    b2-->c1;
    b3-->c1;
    b4-->c1;
    b1-->c2((c2));
    b2-->c2;
    b3-->c2;
    b4-->c2;
```